# Firebase ref() error al usar variable como referencia

Tags: jquery, base-de-datos, firebase

Saludos. Actualmente desarrollo una página cuya función es recuperar datos de Firebase. Durante las pruebas, al establecer la referencia para la obtención de los datos, si lo establezco de manera fija funciona sin problema. Pero al asignar un valor de manera dinámica a través de una variable, arroja el siguiente error en consola:

-Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null at Function.each

Este es el código:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var encuentra = $(producto).val();
var database = firebase.database();
var referencia = database.ref(encuentra);
var reportes={};
referencia.once('value', function(datos)
{
    reportes=datos.val();
    $.each(reportes, function(indice,valor){//muestra datos}
```

Estableciendo ref() como: *database.ref("producto")* no presenta problema, funciona adecuadamente; pero usando la variable *encuentra*, la cual contiene el valor de un *input:text* parece provocar un resultado nulo o alguna inconsistencia al acceder a los datos. Alguna idea?

De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Faltan algunos datos para saber exactamente qué es, pero intenta con la expresión:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var encuentra = $(producto).val();----> var encuentra = $("#producto").val()
var database = firebase.database();
var referencia = database.ref(encuentra);
var reportes={};
referencia.once('value', function(datos)
{
    reportes=datos.val();
    $.each(reportes, function(indice,valor){//muestra datos}
```

me imagino que tienes un `input` tipo texto con `id="producto"`, así que bueno referéncialo con `#` seguido del id del input.